# An example of a context-sensitive grammar for a given language

Tags: formal-languages, formal-grammars, context-sensitive

Consider this language: $L = \{a^nb^ma^nb^m \mid n,m \ge 1\}$. Can we give for this language a context-sensitive grammar?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar#Examples) contains a noncontracting grammar, which can easily be converted to a context-sensitive grammar.

Answer (score 1):

### Your request is easily served!

$$\begin{array}{lcl}
   &S  &\to &abab\\
   &ba &\to &bbBa\\
   &Ba &\to &aB\\
   &Bb &\to &bb\\
   &ba &\to &bAaa\\
   &bA &\to &Ab\\
   &aA &\to &aa\\
\end{array}$$

### There is some theory to help you make sense of this solution.

Let us first consider a simpler language that manifests the same difficulty: $L = \{a^nb^ma^n ∣
n,m \ge 1\}$. Imagine it as a sea of $b$ between the shores of $a$, if you please.

We would like to grow the shores so that they are always the same size. One immediate way is to
have a collection of rules like $a + b^m + a \to aa + b^m + aa $. But we see it will not serve our
needs, as, our collection being finite *(grammars are required to have a finite set of rules)*,
there is always some choice of $m$ that is not accomodated. So evidently there is a trick.

The trick is to introduce a non-terminal *"ship"* that will sail across the sea and deliver the
information from one shore to the other. When the left shore grows, it will send a ship to the
right shore, and when the right shore receives a ship, it will also grow, thus maintaining the
required equilibrium. How can we sail a ship? $Ba \to aB$ is one way to move it one unit of sea
rightwards. What remains to be put in place is a shipyard $ba \to bbBa$ and a port $Bb \to bb$.

Here is what we get:

$$\begin{array}{lcl}
   &S  &\to &bab\\
   &ba &\to &bbBa\\
   &Ba &\to &aB\\
   &Bb &\to &bb\\
\end{array}$$

I am sure you can see how to extend this to your original language: you will need the sea
people to also send some sort of messenger golems $A$ across the land to the sea on the other side of
$b$.

Happy adventures in fantasy grammar land!